# Checking for AND OR condition between two checks

Tags: c#, sql, .net, oop, lambda

Hi I have following linq statement

```
var list=(from c in db.sales 
            where c.id ==id && || c.name==name
            select new model
             {
                 //.....

              });
```

I am having problem with my where clause.

Basically I can get id and name values or either one of them can be null. So I am trying to use where clause with AND OR meaning both condition could be right or either one.

With this where syntax i get intelliscence error. Please let me know how I can use AND OR check in the where clause.

Comment: What do you mean by `intelligence error`?

Comment: Most probably intellisense error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> both condition could be right or either one

You simply need or and do not need and

```
var list=(from c in db.sales 
     where c.id ==id ||  c.name==name
     select new model
     {
             //.....

     });
```

**[The || (or Operator)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx)**

> The conditional-OR operator (||) performs a logical-OR of its bool
>   operands. If the first operand evaluates to true, the second operand
>   isn't evaluated. If the first operand evaluates to false, the second
>   operator determines whether the OR expression as a whole evaluates to
>   true or false, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is just an ordinary OR:

```
where c.id == id || c.name == name
```

This will evaluate to true if `c.id == id` is true, if `c.name == name` is true, or if both are true.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean IntelliSense error. This is obvious, because `&& ||` is not valid C# syntax.

From what you describe, I think you only need the OR operation.

Try changing `&& ||` to just `||`.